# Flutter Codelab: Update ListView on different screen

Tags: dart, flutter

I completed the [Flutter NameGenerator code lab](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Sfshaza/a95ff8ed0473073197d28437c8d68492/raw/6fb529524047c8c093cb6212dfb66635202ba272/main.dart) and wanted to extend it to remove items directly from the "Saved suggestions list".
To do so, I've added the `onTap` handler below which removes the pair from the list.
However, the list doesn't update until I navigate back and reopen the screen again.
How do I immediately update the list on the second screen?

```
void _pushSaved() {
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute<void>(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      final Iterable<ListTile> tiles = _saved.map((WordPair pair) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(
            pair.asPascalCase,
            style: _biggerFont,
          ),
          onTap: () => setState(() {
            _saved.remove(pair);
          }),
        );
      });

      final List<Widget> divided = ListTile.divideTiles(
        context: context,
        tiles: tiles,
      ).toList();

      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Saved Suggestions'),
        ),
        body: new ListView(children: divided),
      );
    }),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why your code doesn't work**

The reason your list doesn't update is that it's a different screen pushed on the Navigator.

Because your `_pushSaved` method is inside the original screen, you call `setState` on that screen and rebuild all the widgets of the original screen.
The pushed screen isn't affected because it's not a child of your original screen.
Rather, the original screen told the Navigator to create a new screen, so it's some subtree of the `Navigator` of your `MaterialApp` and not accessible to you.

**Solution**

Accessing the same live data on different screens is something that's not that easy to do just with `StatefulWidget`s.
Basically, your project has grown complex enough so that it's time to think about a more sophisticated state management solution.
Here's a [video from Google I/O](https://youtu.be/d_m5csmrf7I) about state management that you could check out for some inspiration.

Comment: Brilliant explaination. Thank you! Disappointing that such a seemlingly simple change requires a complete rearchitecture. But that's the joy of coding I guess!